# millisecond in sql tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
SELECT
    CAST(‘2015-01-01 14:48:34.69’ AS DATETIME) FirstVal,
    CAST(‘2015-01-01 14:48:34:69’ AS DATETIME) SecondVal
```

When we look at the answer, there is a difference between the milliseconds part in the result set, whereas you can notice that in the `SELECT` statement I have specified different milliseconds part. The question is why there is a difference in the millisecond part even though I have different value selected?

[image]

Comment: I tried SELECT
    CAST('2015-01-01 14:48:34:665' AS DATETIME) FirstVal,
    CAST('2015-01-01 14:48:34.665' AS DATETIME) SecondVal and i got very strange result 
2015-01-01 14:48:34.667
2015-01-01 14:48:34.667

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DATETIME` has an accuracy of 3.33ms - you will **never** see a value with a  `.069` stored in a `DATETIME` - you only ever get `.xx0`, `.xx3` and `.xx7`.

If you need millisecond precision, use `DATETIME2(3)` (introduced in SQL Server **2008**) as your datatype instead.

Comment: The question has .69 not .069

Comment: @MartinSmith: yeah, I saw that - but I was wondering if that means `.690` really - or `.069` - just had to take a guess

Comment: Yep looks like `:69` is interpreted as `:069` and rounded, whereas `.69` is just interpreted as `.690`. The colon notation looks like just treats the number after as miliseconds. `14:48:34:3 = 2015-01-01 14:48:34.003`

Answer (score 0):

you have selected Diff Value
in First Value:-34.69 and Second Value :- 34:69.
you can see both value diff so out put diff.

Answer (score 0):

[Click here to see the diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOUS8.jpg)

It's because you have selected different time is milliseconds.